# Code which worked several days ago to create bigquery job has stopped working

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform

Starting a couple days ago, all my calls to jobs.insert fail. I am using the Google .Net client SDK on Azure, so I can't (easily) get a network trace. Summary of code is below.

```
    JobsResource.InsertMediaUpload insertMediaUpload 
        = new JobsResource.InsertMediaUpload(bigqueryService, job, projectId, stream, contentType);
    insertMediaUpload.ProgressChanged += UploadOnProgressChanged;

    var task = insertMediaUpload.UploadAsync();

    StringBuilder sbwait = new StringBuilder("waiting: ");
    while (!task.IsCompleted) {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

...

```
static private void UploadOnProgressChanged(IUploadProgress process)
{
    string excpStr = process.Exception != null ? process.Exception.Message : "";
    Logger.Info($"IN UploadOnProgressChanged: {process.Status} :  {process.BytesSent} : {excpStr}");
}
```

My log has

"IN UploadOnProgressChanged: Failed :  0 : An error occurred while sending the request."

Fails pretty consistently after 20 iterations of the while (!task.IsCompleted) loop.

When I run this locally it is successful. Perhaps someone recognizes and understand the error message that the library is generating.

Comment: Not a fix but an advice : get process.Exception.ToString() instead of process.Exception.Message to have accurate details about error.

Comment: Also, check the time between process startup and error  : i suspect it will always be the same, and your underlying error could be a timeout due to unavailable remote server, hence the "0 bytes" uploaded.